JavaFX application "Failed to launch JVM" if using jpackage
I am creating an application using JavaFx, after doing some testing (that went totally fine),
I wanted to use jpackage in order to create an installer for my program, for that I used this command:
jpackage --input . --dest . --main-jar .\Application.jar --main-class seeg2.number.application.Main --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-21.0.3_windows-x64_bin-jmods\javafx-jmods-21.0.3" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.base,javafx.media,java.desktop --win-shortcut --win-menu --name "Application" --icon .\icon.ico

The installation process worked out, however trying to run the application always led to a popout saying "Failed to launch JVM".
I tried reinstalling the wix toolset and switching the javafx aswell as javasdk versions for my project, without any success though.
Running the .jar file from cmd also works fine, I guess something is up with the jpackage command but I could now figure out what it is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What happens with jpackage --win-console --input . --dest . --main-jar .\Application.jar --main-class seeg2.number.application.Main --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-21.0.3_windows-x64_bin-jmods\javafx-jmods-21.0.3" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.base,javafx.media,java.desktop --win-shortcut --win-menu --name "Application" --icon .\icon.ico when you try to launch it using the console? Odd (and probably messy) to use the same directory for input and dest

Thanks for the help, was able to debug it using the console.
My SettingsManager tried to create a file that was already in the installation directory and therefore threw an exception.

Community wiki answer:
The author solved the problem by himself, stated in the comments:

Thanks for the help, was able to debug it using the console. My
SettingsManager tried to create a file that was already in the
installation directory and therefore threw an exception. –
1212
CommentedJun 30 at 14:31

